# Injected Page is null

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

After upgrading an angular nativescript project to the current versions of angular, typescript, tns, etc.. I'm getting a runtime error stating:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'actionBarHidden' of null at new
>   AppComponent...

The code that previously worked to hide the action bar looks like this:

```
import {Page} from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    constructor(page: Page) {
        page.actionBarHidden = true;
    }
}
```

Why is page null after the injection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the earlier versions the root was always a `Frame`, so by default there will be a `Page`.

But with the latest version, you are allowed to define flexible root components and any number of frames (`page-router-outlet`) within your app. So there won't be a default `Frame` / `Page` created within app component. `Page` can be injected only into the components those are loaded inside the `page-router-outlet`.

Comment: Nice, here is more info under 'Angular Flexible Root Composition': https://www.nativescript.org/blog/announcing-the-nativescript-4.1-release I just commented out all my page injections and actionBarHidden = true and it seems to be ok. Now I have fix the similar issue with setting attributes on injected page inside of modals, but it looks like that link goes into that also.

Answer (score 0):

If TLDR the above link, the quick fix for me was to replace:

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>` with `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>`

in app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Moving code to `ngOnInit` solved it for me